# Shift/reduce conflict with C-like grammar under Bison

Tags: bison

I've been working on a C-like grammar for my personal amusement. However, I've been running into shift/reduce conflicts, and I'm quite sure they could be resolved.

Right now my `expressions` look like this, in a simplified form, stripped of actions:

```
%left '+' '-'

%%
expr
 : NUMBER
 | IDENTIFIER
 | expr '+' expr
 | expr '-' expr
 /* other operators like '*', '/', etc. */
 | expr '(' expr ')' /* function call */
%%
```

However, this results in shift/reduce conflicts: the parser is unsure about how to treat parentheses. From what `-v` tells me, it is unclear whether an expression like `expr '+' expr '('` should reduce `expr '+' expr` into `expr` or shift the parenthesis.

Obviously, I want the parenthesis to be shifted. `foo % bar(4)` shouldn't end up being `(foo % bar)(4)`. However, I've had no success using the `%prec` directive to that mean. Adding `%left FUNCALL` and `%prec FUNCALL` after the rule yields no change.

I know that the default path Bison's LALR parsers will go when encountering a shift/reduce will be to shift, and that I could just use `%expect` to <strike>fix</strike> work around the problem. However, one conflict is generated for each expression, and would I ever need to change that list, I'll also need to change the `%expect` declaration, which looks like a rather ugly solution to me. Besides, I'm sure one of you wise kids have a solution to that problem.

My goal is to have a rule similar to the one above, for which Bison will know that whenever it encounters the `'('` from the function call rule, it has shift the parenthesis, without a possible shift/reduce conflict. For the record, my use of the `%prec` directive is the following, so if I'm just doing it wrong you can correct me. It does have the shift/reduce conflict.

```
%left '+' '-'
%left FUNCALL

%%

expr
    : NUMBER
    | IDENTIFIER
    | expr '+' expr
    | expr '-' expr
    /* other operators like '*', '/', etc. */
    | expr '(' expr ')' %prec FUNCALL /* function call */

%%
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add `%left '('` to your precedence rules (or `%nonassoc '('` might be better).

The way that precedence works to resolve shift/reduce conflicts in yacc/bison is that it compares the precedence of the *rule* to be reduced with the precedence of the *token* to be shifted.  In your example, the conflict is between reducing `expr: expr '+' expr` and shifting a `'('`, so to resolve it, you need a precedence on `'('` (and you want it to be higher than the rule, which comes from `'+'`)

The `%prec` directive just sets the precedence of a rule, overriding its default precedence which comes from the first token on its rhs.  It doesn't affect the precedence of tokens that appear in the rule in any way.

Comment: Oh, I see. I can't really afford `%nonassoc '('` since it would break nested parentheses altogether unless I'm missing something else, but I get your point. Thank you.

Comment: nested parens should not involve any conflicts, so `%nonassoc` should not be a problem -- precedence rules ONLY matter for resolving conflicts