# Is this a semantic error or the syntax error ?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main( )
{


    int x, y;

    y=x(5);
    return 0;
}
```

MSVC 2010 compiler gives the following error:

```
Error   1   error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments    c:\users\ae\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\text\text\text.cpp    13

2   IntelliSense: expression must have (pointer-to-) function type  c:\users\ae\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\text\text\text.cpp    13
```

Is this a semantic error or the syntax error ?

Comment: An error of kind invalid operand is semantic error, Syntax error is an error that is not valid according to language syntax (correct format). `y = x(5);` every token is valid and it can parse correctly (as `x` is a valid function name). but thing is `x` is not function it is `int` viable you can't call it a kind of invalid operand-so Semantic error.-- NOTE: `5(x)` will be a syntax error.

Comment: Also adding one more example of semantic error `int a[10]; *p;` then `++a` would be semantic error but not syntax. While `++p` is valid.

Comment: To proof it try this: write `#include<stdio.h> int main(){ int y; y = x(5); return 0;}` (removed `x` from declaration) then compile with `-c` flag with gcc it it compile. but try to link it with a header file with declaration of `x` as int variable it will causes error. Hence  `y  = x(5);` is syntactically correct and not a syntax error.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan What makes you say that `5(x)` is a syntax error? The grammar in C99 6.5.2:1 is pretty clear (and it says that `5(x)`is a postfix-expression).

Comment: The tag `compiler` should be applied to questions concerning the programming of compilers or for questions about the detailed inner workings of compilers. Don't use `compiler` for questions about options and settings for a particular compiler, use the name of the compiler you are interested in instead.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I commented for `C` (not for C99), Give it a try it will be syntax error for sure. I will read the section from C99. Thanks!

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan The C language is defined by standards, identified for concision by the year they were published. The “C99 standard” defines a version of the C language. In what C standard do you claim that `5(x)` is a syntax error? PS: I gave it a try and `5(x)` results in a typing error, just like `x(5)`. You can see an example of syntax error in KepaniHaole's answer.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Yes I tried again and you are correct `5(x)` is semantic error. I read [this grammar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068637/shift-reduce-problem-with-c-like-grammar-under-bison) and it says `5` is valid expression (I don't understand but may be 5 treated as function address, but not sure). Earlier I was tiring `y = (5)x;` that is syntax error. - Thanks to correct me.

Comment: Who cares? It's an error either way. You still have to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Semantic. It would be legit c syntax if `x` was a function that took 1 argument -- but it's just an `int`.

It'd be a syntax error if you did this:

```
int x, y;

y=x((5;
return 0;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it's a semantic error, specifically, a type error. The token sequence `y = x(5)` is well formed, and the `x(5)` part is parsed as a function call expression. The error is that `x` does not evaluate to a function pointer, but rather to an `int`.

Comment: I would like to add to know `x(5)` is invalid it need to refer symbol-table/to know type of `x` that is postponed to semantic phase as can't be done in syntax analysis phase.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: well, there are many ways you can write a compiler, so I don't want to presume too many details (e.g. "phases"). I imagine that a real-world C++ compiler doesn't use Joey Textbook's First Parser...

Comment: Yes but as I know 'C as formal language is a CSL', feature like Declare first then use variable make it context-sentitive instead context-free and as we don't know any efficient parsing technique for CSL every C compiler will post-pond type check work in semantic phase. So I added.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: As far as I understand it, type checking has nothing to do with being context-free. Even in a context-free language you have to type-check your AST. The "context" comes from the fact that the parser needs to know the meaning of a symbol in order to parse a token sequence and determine *what kind of syntax* you have; luckily, C is "almost" context free and the only thing you need to disambiguate is whether a symbol is a variable or a type name, which can be solved quite easily.

Answer (score 2):

If it was a syntax error it would say so. It's a semantic error. It's all about the meanings of the identifiers in your code.

Answer (score 2):

It would clear the syntax analysis pass because it just check weather there any syntax error or not.
I mean `y=x(5);` ,

> it says that 5 in passed in function x and value returned to y.

but, the meaning is not assigned at parsing time that x is a integer variable not procedure.
So, on semantic analysis when logical meanings are assigned it come to know this is not possible.

So, considering this as **logical error** we can say that is **semantic error**.